Is it possible to parse a object of type CompilerOptions to a string or object for the tsconfig.json?
Assume I have an object of the type CompilerOptions with the following contents:
{
  target: ScriptTarget.ES2022,
  esModuleInterop: true,
  module: ModuleKind.CommonJS,
  moduleResolution: ModuleResolutionKind.NodeJs,
}

Some types could be missing; however, that does not matter to this question.
Is there a way to parse this to a string or object that could be written to a tsconfig.json and create a valid one? For example, ModuleKind.CommonJS should be replaced with "commonjs" in the outputted config.
I know that the function ts.convertCompilerOptionsFromJson basically does the opposite of what I want. It converts a valid JSON object from the tsconfig.json to a valid object of the type CompilerHost. Is there a similar one in the opposite direction?

It would be great if the downvoter could explain why he downvoted so that I could improve my question.

(didn't downvote) This looks like a duplicate of this question, where the answer is "it can't be done" (presumably that just means you'd have to write the parser yourself). Does that fully address your question (even if you don't like the answer) or is something missing?

@jcalz, Thank you so much! I'm sorry, I did not find that question when searching. I've marked it as a duplicate.
